# removeClass in array name does not work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a class after I click a link using removeClass in jQuery. But it does not work for me.

```
<a href="#" onclick="xxx();"></a>// actually i have more complicated but to make it easy to see my problem. 

**Original div**
<div class c1 c2 ></div>


**In javascript**

$("#"+arr[1]).removeClass(' c2').addClass('c3');
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div id='001' class ='c1 c2'></div>
<div id='002' class ='c1 c2'></div>
<div id='003' class ='c1 c2'></div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
// call cookie to deal with last clicked div.
var ca="mycookie"+user_id;


    ca = new Array();
    ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (var w in ca)

    NmeVal  = new Array();
    NmeVal  = ca[w].split('cki_uid%3D302%26last_open_inbx%3D'); 

$('div[id="'+NmeVal[1]+'"]').removeClass('inbx_unread').addClass('inbx_unr_after_java_click');
```

What I will say: I use cookie to remember the last cliked div. Because I have a div call selected div that must be change all the time people click. ANd it must remove the old class when do another click and so on.

Just like facebook left Nav. in inbox page.

PS: I´m sorry I did not show the code form beginning of question because my variable look so bad.

**UPDATE 3  FULL CODE**

```
    function call_inbox_data(user_id, recipient_id, sender_id, c_id, elm2hide, unread_msg, cr_id) { 


  //call cookie
    var ca="myccokie"+user_id;


        ca = new Array();
        ca = document.cookie.split(';');

        for (var w in ca)

        NmeVal  = new Array();
        NmeVal  = ca[w].split('cki_uid%3D302%26last_open_inbx%3D'); 




    }

    /////Here work perfect
    if (unread_msg !="") {
    for (var f in unread_msg){  //LOOP  
    if (unread_msg[f]!= c_id)   {   
    $("#"+unread_msg[f]).addClass('inbx_unread'); // 

    }

    }
      }



    // But not here  I have changed many ways but none of them help.

    $('div[name="'+NmeVal[1]+'"]').removeClass('inbx_unread');
    $('div[name="'+NmeVal[1]+'"]').addClass('inbx_unr_after_java_click');
```

Comment: i think the problem lies with your selector make a fiddle of your problem

Comment: it´s array. I have a set of array that repersent the name of divs i have.

Comment: Name of the divs..??Can you show us full code..??

Comment: Is that your full HTML? As it is written, `c1` and `c2` are not part of the value of the `class` attribute.

Comment: Show us the jquery script

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cwT4Y/ is a fiddle that seems to do what you want with roughly the code you have. Are you sure that you are getting the right ID from the array? Try outputting the jquery selector in the console window to verify it.

Comment: What's the value of `NmeVal`?

Comment: Hi I have update evrything again.

Answer (score 1):

**As per your comment** ,the `arr` is an array of names for the divs then try like

```
$('div[name="'+arr[1]+'"]').removeClass('c2').addClass('c3');
```

OR

```
$('div[name="'+arr[1]+'"]').removeClass('c2');
$('div[name="'+arr[1]+'"]').addClass('c3');
```

If the arr is an array of `ids` then try like

```
$('#'+arr[1]]).removeClass('c2').addClass('c3');
```

Comment: Hei it does remove class but did not add the new class :S

Comment: Hi, I have test it...I really don´t understand why it does not work ..
This looks very easy and simple, but it not :S

Comment: Alert the `NmeVal` and tell me what u getting exactly

Comment: Hi the alert of   NmeVal[1]  I get 690  /// the id of this div.

Comment: I´m sorry, if i say it as name. 
The last method you gave me i have used it and doesn´t work either :S